# How to update hook state in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state and I am updating it in a loop. I have an issue where  the state that was previously updated did not have enough time to update so I get undefined values.

Example:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
```

On every second item I am changing the email prop but want to keep the password prop as is.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 1) {
      if (i % 2) setErrors({ email: test${i}, password: errors.password });
      else setErrors({ email: errors.email, password: test2${i} });
      console.log('err', errors);
    }
```

The result ends up giving me

> email:test1

and

> password:undefined

Is it possible to update state like this or am I going on about it the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe this approach will work? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: useState is async. It is not accessible after you set. You get your values at the next render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `updater` version of `useState` and `spread` all properties overwriting `email`

```
if (i % 2) setErrors(prevErros =>({ ...prevErros, email: test${i}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set once at end? You shouldn't be calling the same setState function multiple times in one hook

```js
let currentEmail = null;
let currentPassword = null;

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 1) {
  if (i % 2) {
    currentEmail = `test_${i}`;
  } else {
    currentPassword = `test2_${i}`;
  }
}

setErrors({ email: currentEmail, password: currentPassword });
```